# Dictionary Keys are columns from dataframe and values are feature type of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

Write a function which returns a dictionary where keys are the column names of the data frame and the values are one of "numeric", "categorical", "ordinal", "date/time", or "text", corresponding to the feature type of each column.

I was able to import the data as a data frame. I then converted the df into a dictionary. I then got the keys as the columns, but I'm having trouble with assigning the values ( "numeric", "categorical", "ordinal", "date/time", or "text") to each column.

```py
# Importing the pandas package
import pandas as pd

def helper(df):
    # Creating data frame from csv.gz File. Enter the appropriate file path
    cobra = pd.read_csv(df, compression='gzip')
    cobra_dict = cobra.to_dict()
    dict_keys = cobra.keys()

    print(dict_keys)


helper(df)
```

```py
Expected Results:
In [1]: helper(df[['offense_id','beat','x','y']])
Out[1]: {'beat': 'categorical',
         'offense_id': 'ordinal',
         'x': 'numeric',
         'y': 'numeric'}
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: The question is some of my columns are categorical, some are numeric...how do I classify my columns as such then print it out like the 'Expected Results' shown above?

Comment: @Vaibis did my answer below help at all?

Comment: It did. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

you might need to create a mapping dict if you want exactly as your output above but this should work, we can `zip` the columns and your `dtypes` into two lists and create a `dict` with columns as the keys and values as dtypes.

```
def helper(df):
    # Creating data frame from csv.gz File. Enter the appropriate file path
    cobra = pd.read_csv(df, compression='gzip')
    cobra_dict = dict(zip(cobra.columns.tolist(),cobra .dtypes.tolist()))

    print(cobra_dict)
```

on my own sample df.

```
print(my_dict)    
{'A': dtype('O'), 'B': dtype('int64'), 'C': dtype('float64')}
```